# HMVC integration with hybridauth codeigniter extension

Tags: codeigniter, hmvc, hybridauth

I am working on a project in which I am using codeigniter's HMVC & hybridauth extension.  HMVC is working fine. But I have problems in running hybridauth extension. After the initial setup for hybridauth, when I run it the following two errors are displayed:

> ```
> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined property: CI::$hybridauthlib
>
> Filename: MX/Loader.php
>
> Line Number: 165
>
>
>
> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\SADD_contest\system\core\Exceptions.php:185)
>
> Filename: Hybrid/Auth.php
>
> Line Number: 354
> ```

I think the second error is due to first error..Is the hybridauth library not compatible with MX_controller? I am a total newbie both in these two library. How can I resolve the issue?

Comment: Exactly how and where are you loading the library? Click [edit] and show us your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can check my answer at this url [Hybrid Auth with Codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10422573/hybrid-auth-with-codeigniter) which is the code that i use for hybridauth and HMVC ..